# Plants for a brackish water tank?

Tags: aquarium, aquatic-plants

Anyone know some plant salt resistant for this type of tank? I need a some reference cause this tank have a bit percentage of salinity in the wate, is lower percentatge but this can harm the plants.

What plants can i use here?

Comment: i do not have an answer to this but you can take a look here https://m.liveaquaria.com/article/29/?aid=29 until you get an answer.

Comment: Basically mangroves, java ferns, and some types of marine algae such as caulerpa. There are some grasses as well but most sea grasses are very difficult to grow in captivity, they tend to require deep, well established sandbeds.

Comment: @Jestep How i put a mangrove in a water tank, this is a tree is really big or exist some kind of small mangrove?

Comment: What organisms live in the tank?

Comment: @Raystafarian i will put in the tank a few carinotetraodon travancoricus and few brachygobius xanthozona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For brackish water, your plant selection really depends on the salinity of the tank. In general, plants need nutrients and light. Again, not knowing your light setup or your substrate is a little bit of a challenge. I'm going to assume an inert substrate like sand and low to medium light.

Assuming you have a brackish tank, not saltwater (which it seems you will as the species you intend to keep - carinotetraodon travancoricus & brachygobius xanthozona - are freshwater to brackish and would not survive in a saltwater environment) your easiest plants are plants that don't need to root.

1. **Java fern**
2. **Anubias**

These can be attached to driftwood or rock as the roots don't need to be buried. Usually you can take your wood or rock out of the tank, dab a little **cyanoacrylate** superglue on the **rhyzome**, stick it to the the wood/rock and spray it with a little water. The water should make the glue cure immediately and since you're using cyanoacrylate, it is chemically inert - meaning it won't react in the tank. The same can be done for Anubias.

Java fern is great - you can get regular java fern, narrow leaf, trident or my favorite windelov. They all do fine.

For anubias, some of my favorite are anubias barteri and anubias barteri vars - nana, nana petite coffeefolia). Again these are attached the same way, or they are placed into a pot of some sort - you don't need them to root.

3. Another easy plant that's low-light will be **cryptocoryne wendtii**. This will root, but it's usually not very fussy.

Depending on your local plant laws -

4. **Anacharis** is pretty much a weed. I wouldn't recommend it, but it would do fine.

A few others you might want to try -

5. Ceratopteris siliquosa and thalictroides (**water sprite**)
6. **Hornwort** (Ceratophyllum demersum)
7. There are reports that micro-sword (**Lilaeopsis brasiliensis**) can carpet a brackish tank pretty well, but I've had trouble keeping that alive in a dirted tank before so..

Your best bet, which I've saved for last because I've never kept it, is **red mangrove (Rhizophora mangle)** - it does need high lighting though, but it will keep well in saltwater too. They plant and the leaves stay above the substrate.

Again, I haven't included all the options or the full plant profiles - you'll want to double check you have the right temperature, **lighting, pH**, hardness gH, hardness kH and salinity. You'll also want to make sure you know how to care for the plants - trimming the dead as well as propagating them properly.

I'm not sure about the goby, but I know dwarf puffers love a nice planted tank. Beware though, both those fish are bottom dwellers and the puffers can get pretty territorial, so putting in a lot of hiding spots is a great idea.

*Added Bonus* -

If you get some good sized (zebra) nerite snails, the puffers shouldn't be interested in eating them and they can thrive in all fresh, brackish or salt (as long as it's not soft water) and they can take care of most unwanted algae.

Comment: Yes, I will use sand, brackish tank not saltwater, and is a low tech tank so plants with hard requeriment maybe can have a problems in this tank.  Nice answer, really good options and thanks for all the explanation. What about Vallisneria spiralis? Is a good option? 

About puffers alimentation (maybe is better make other question), they dom't will eat Zebras? i will feed them with planorbis so...

Comment: Is your water naturally soft? I've always had hard water and need to run ro/di. Puffers won't generally eat large snails, too big. Val might work, but it's finicky in my experience.

Comment: My natural water is hard, but i use osmosis water for obtain soft water. Idk what is ro/di. Why? i will try to use the good parameters for this type of puffers, this include pH, kH, gH and salinity.

Comment: Reverse osmosis dionization.